# Evaluate the sum $\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}^2 i^k$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Given a positive integer $k$, is it possible to evaluate the following sum?
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}^2 i^k\,\,\,?
$$

[I know just for $k=0$ the sum is $\binom{2n}{n} \approx 4^n/\sqrt{n}$..]

Comment: $f(n,m)=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni^2 i^{m-2}i^2=n^2\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i-1}^2i^{m-2}$

$\implies f(n,m)=n^2f(n-1,m-2)$

Comment: why the second sum goes up to n-1?

Comment: $$f(n,m)=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom ni^2 i^{m-2}i^2=n^2\sum_{i-1=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i-1}^2i^{m-2}$$

$$\implies f(n,m)=n^2f(n-1,m-2)$$

Comment: Oh, ok.. so, we miss only the case $k=1$, right?